# Jasmine-Node Require *

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine

In my Jasmine-Node spec_helper I have `require("../app/test")` and it pulls in that `test` file just fine.  But if I try `require("../app/*")`, I get `Error: Cannot find module '../app/*'`.

Is there a way to pull in all the files/sub-dirs of a directory like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to accomplish what you want, the easiest probably being to create an `index.js` in your `./app` directory. This `index.js` would in turn reference all the modules inside that directory, and export them:

```
exports.foo = require("./foo");
exports.bar = require("./bar");
```

If you want to do it dynamically, you will have to write some code:

```
var fs = require("fs");

fs.readdir("./app", function(err, files) {
    if(err) console.error(err);
    for(var i = 0, len = files.length; i < len; i++) {
        require("./app/" + files[i]);
    }
});
```

For more info on how node loads modules, [here's the relevant docs](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html) and about [folders as modules](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#folders_as_Modules) in particular.

Unfortunately, Jed's answer here is wrong.